# Global variable in selfhosted ServiceStack server

Tags: c#, servicestack

I need to have some "global" variables in my servicestack selfhosted server, like myList here:

```
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        AppHost appHost;

        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            appHost = new AppHost();
            appHost.Init();
            appHost.Start(ListeningOn);

            appHost.Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());
            appHost.ContentTypeFilters.Register(ServiceStack.Common.Web.ContentType.ProtoBuf, (reqCtx, res, stream) => ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Serialize(stream, res), ProtoBuf.Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create your ServiceStack http listener application with a singleton AppHost.
        /// </summary> 
        public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
        {
            public int intAppHost;
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of your ServiceStack application, with the specified name and assembly containing the services.
            /// </summary>
            public AppHost() : base("CTServer HttpListener", typeof(MainService).Assembly) { }

            /// <summary>
            /// Configure the container with th e necessary routes for your ServiceStack application.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="container">The built-in IoC used with ServiceStack.</param>
            public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
            {
                Routes
                  .Add<ReqPing>("/ping");
            }
        }
    }

public class MainService : Service
{
    public RespPing Any(ReqPing request)
    {
        // Add a value to a global list here
        myList.Add(myData);

        RespPing response = new RespPing();
        return response;
    }   
}
```

Where should I define myList, and how can I access it from that location? And how can I do it in a thread safe manner?
In this case the functionality is to store a certain value received and check in another instance if this valus is already in the list.
Is this an appropriate way to share data among instances, or should I follow another path?

Thanks!
Mattia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) as ServiceStack Services are simply C# classes that are autowired with your registered dependencies each time.

So normal C# rules apply, if it's global you can just make it static but as ASP.NET and HttpListener are multi-threaded you need to protect access to it, e.g:

```
public class MainService : Service
{
    static List<MyData> myList = new List<MyData>();

    public RespPing Any(ReqPing request)
    {
        // Add a value to a global list here
        lock(myList) myList.Add(myData);

        RespPing response = new RespPing();
        return response;
    }   
}
```

The alternative is to register a singleton dependency and have it autowired to all the services that need it each time, e.g:

#### Normal Dependency

```
public class GlobalState
{
    List<MyData> myList = new List<MyData>();

    public void AddData(MyData myData)
    {
        lock(myList) myList.Add(myData);
    }
}
```

#### AppHost

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    //All Registrations and Instances are singleton by default in Funq
    container.Register(new GlobalState()); 
}
```

#### Service

```
public class MainService : Service
{
    public GlobalState GlobalState { get; set; }

    public RespPing Any(ReqPing request)
    {
        // Add a value to a global list here
        GlobalState.AddData(myData);

        RespPing response = new RespPing();
        return response;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand that is not a ServiceStack related question but my problem raised working with ServiceStack...
And sometimes some basic C# rules are missed... I tried your first solution forgetting 'static'...
The second is interesting, I'll try that to better understand how Funq works... 
Thanks for the prompt answer!
Mattia

Comment: @MattiaDurli no worries, but it's best to tag it with C# so others can help answer it.